# Best way to by column and aggregation on another column

Tags: sql, hive

I want to create a rank column using existing rank and binary columns. Suppose for example a table with ID, RISK, CONTACT, DATE. The existing rank is RISK, say 1,2,3,NULL, with 3 being the highest. The binary-valued is CONTACT with 0,1 or FAILURE/SUCESS. I want to create a new RANK that will order by RISK once a certain number of successful contacts has been exceeded.

For example, suppose the constraint is a minimum of 2 successful contacts. Then the rank should be created as follows in the two instances below:

Instance 1. Three ID, all have a min of two successful contacts. In that case the rank mirrors the risk:

```
ID  risk  contact  date  rank
1   3     S        1     3
1   3     S        2     3
1   3     F        3     3
1   3     F        4     3
2   2     S        1     2
2   2     S        2     2
2   2     F        3     2
2   2     F        4     2
3   1     S        1     1
3   1     S        2     1
3   1     S        3     1
```

Instance 2. Suppose ID=1 has only one successful contact. In that case it is relegated to the lowest rank, rank=1, while ID=2 gets the highest value, rank=3, and ID=3 maps to rank=2 because it satisfies the constraint but has a lower risk value than ID=2:

```
ID  risk  contact  date  rank
1   3     S        1     1
1   3     F        2     1
1   3     F        3     1
1   3     F        4     1
2   2     S        1     3
2   2     S        2     3
2   2     F        3     3
2   2     F        4     3
3   1     S        1     2
3   1     S        2     2
3   1     S        3     2
```

This is SQL, specifically Hive. Thanks in advance.

Edit - I think Gordon Linoff's code does it correctly. In the end, I used three interim tables. The code looks like that:

First,

```
--numerize risk, contact
select A.* ,
       case when A.risk = 'H' then 3
            when A.risk = 'M' then 2
            when A.risk = 'L' then 1
            when A.risk is NULL then NULL
            when A.risk = 'NULL' then NULL
       else -999 end as RISK_RANK,
       case when A.contact = 'Successful' then 1
       else NULL end as success
```

Second,

```
-- sum_successes_by_risk
select A.* ,
       B.sum_successes_by_risk
from T  as A 
inner join 
(select A.person, A.program, A.risk, sum(a.success) as sum_successes_by_risk
 from T as A
 group by A.person, A.program, A.risk
 ) as B
on A.program = B.program 
 and A.person = B.person
 and A.risk = B.risk
```

Third,

```
--Create table that contains only max risk category
select A.* ,
       B.max_risk_rank
from T as A 
inner join 
(select A.person, max(A.risk_rank) as max_risk_rank
 from T as A
 group by A.person
 ) as B
on A.person = B.person
   and A.risk_rank = B.max_risk_rank
```

Answer (score 0):

This is hard to follow, but I think you just want window functions:

```
select t.*,
       (case when sum(case when contact = 'S' then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by id) >= 2
             then risk
             else 1
        end) as new_risk
from t;
```